# Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

И еще одна убедительная просьба - в рамках предвыборной кампании подписаться самим и привлечь как можно больше сторонников в нашу группу в «вконтакте» - Глава МО «Васильевский» Константин Чебыкин.

Comment: Мгм, вообще-то "одна" просьба состоит из двух: 1) подписаться самим и 2) привлечь как можно больше сторонников

Answer (score 2):

Тире перед изложением содержания вопроса лучше заменить двоеточием. Нужно поставить точку перед подписью, завершив содержание сообщения. Подпись вынести в новую строку. "Глава" - обычно слово неформальное (с маленькой буквы, если оно не значится в уставе или штатном расписании). Наименование "вконтакте" лучше написать в том виде, в котором оно зарегистрировано ("ВКонтакте"), чтобы не создавать новый вариант с нарушением русской грамматики (без пробела); предлог перед этим названием заменить на "во" (иначе не прочитать).

Answer (score 0):

И еще **одна** убедительная просьба: в рамках предвыборной кампании подписаться самим и привлечь как можно больше сторонников в нашу группу  ВКонтакте. Глава МО «Васильевский» Константин Чебыкин.

Пояснения

1) Двоеточие желательно, так как раскрывает содержание местоимения "одна".

2) **Предлог "В" лучше пропустить** по аналогии с оформлением официальной страницы: **Впервые ВКонтакте? Моментальная регистрация.**

**Примечание**: создать группу ВКонтакте - это очень "трудная" фраза, ее записывают весьма разнообразно, например:

Может ли группа **вконтакте** заменить сайт? Как оформить группу **В Контакте.** Подпишись, если ты **в контакте**.  Но вот второй предлог В/ВО вроде бы  никто не использует.